# How to get this code with browser based solanaweb3

Tags: web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter

I want to transfer  solana  from one account to another , I am using browser frotend js, **not nodejs** how I can get  this  secret key  and  transfer data,

Please do not  suggest this

```
 var from = web3.Keypair.generate();
    // Generate a new random public key
    var to = web3.Keypair.generate();
```

Please suggest with public key  since from web wallet I am getting  only  the public key

I need to understand how  I can get this  array with web3js, or wallet-adapter or splToken

```
var web3 = require("@solana/web3.js");
// Address: asdasvfhgasomeaddress
const DEMO_FROM_SECRET_KEY = new Uint8Array([
    37, 21, 197, 185, 105, 201, 212, 148, 164, 108, 251, 159, 174, 252, 43, 246,
    225, 156, 38, 203, 99, 42, 244, 73, 252, 143, 34, 239, 15, 222, 217, 91, 132,
    167, 105, 60, 17, 211, 120, 243, 197, 99, 113, 34, 76, 127, 190, 18, 91, 246,
    121, 93, 189, 55, 165, 129, 196, 104, 25, 157, 209, 168, 165, 149,
]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how browser based dapps work. The app never gets access to the user's private key. You also can't sign a transaction without the user's private key. Instead you can request the user sign a transaction, and the wallet browser extension will pop up and display that request to the user. Their browser extension holds the key, and never exposes it to the dapp.  It is responsible for doing all signing using that key.

Check our the wallet-adapter docs here for an example: https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/blob/master/APP.md